# Using Select Layer by Location in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-location

I'm trying to export a selection ( "select by location") using Copy features.

The selection is from the "Layer1".

[image]

It apparently executes the selection, but the copy feature is made by the original layer and not by the selection.

I am using NEW_SELECTION in "selection type" of the "Select Layer by location" menu.

In the "Copy Features" the input feature is equal to the original file name.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"NEW_SELECTION" actually refers to the selection type. Selection types include:

> NEW_SELECTION —The resulting selection replaces any existing
>   selection. This is the default.
>
> ADD_TO_SELECTION —The resulting
>   selection is added to an existing selection if one exists. If no
>   selection exists, this is the same as the NEW_SELECTION option.
>
> REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION —The resulting selection is removed from an
>   existing selection. If no selection exists, this option has no effect.
>
> SUBSET_SELECTION —The resulting selection is combined with the
>   existing selection. Only records that are common to both remain
>   selected.
>
> SWITCH_SELECTION —Switches the selection. All records that
>   were selected are removed from the selection; all records that were
>   not selected are added to the selection. The Expression is ignored
>   when this option is specified.
>
> CLEAR_SELECTION —Clears or removes any
>   selection. The Expression is ignored when this option is specified.
>   [Source](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//001700000071000000)

To get the results of one tool to be used as the input for another, you will need to mark that output as a parameter (right click-->check Model Parameter)

> If you need the outputs of your model tool to appear in the Results
>   window, you must make those outputs model parameters. For example, if
>   your tool outputs an HTML file and you want the user to be able to
>   click on that file from the Results window you must make the HTML
>   output file a model parameter.

[More on Model Parameters - ArcGIS 10](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/creating-model-parameter.htm)